# Perl - Conditional splitting of a file into multiple based on floating numeric value

Tags: perl

I want to split a file contents to multiple outputfiles by comparing floating number present as string in the last line. For example, the file below contains more than 100K such lines:

```
Start:/abc/def
.....
End 1.2
Start:/xyz/uvw
.....
End 2.8
```

I want to print every lines from `Start` to `End` to `OUTFILE1` if `End` contains values between 1 and 1.9. Otherwise print all such lines to `OUTFILE2` if `End` contains values between 2 and 2.9. Likewise, multiple output files have to be generated based on discrete range of the floating value upto 10 ie 0-1, 1-2,2-3 and so on. If there are many floating values in a given range, then entries should get appended to output files.

The code I tried below has issues in comparing floating number correctly and also problems in conditionally emptying the array contents to required output files. Any suggestions how to fix it?

```
foreach $lineIn(@file1_list) {
  $_ = $lineIn;

  if (/Start:/) {
    $pattern1 = 1;
  } elsif(/End\s/) {
    my @slackno = split / \s + /, $_; 
    $pattern2 = 1;
    push(@buflines, $_);
  }
  if ($pattern1 = ~1 and $pattern2 = ~0) {
    push(@buflines, $_);
  } else {
    $pattern1 = 0;
    $pattern2 = 0;
  }
}
if ($slackno[3] >= 2.0 and $slackno[3] <= 2.9) {
  foreach(@buflines) {
    print FILE2 $_;
  }
}
close(FILE2);
```

Comment: So just two output files then?  What with `End 7.4`?  The title hints at more files.

Comment: Yes, as many output files to generate based on discrete ranges of floating values

Comment: "Yes" on which part? :)  Is it: two files, or one for each (near) integer range that happens to be in the file?

Comment: For example, discrete ranges 0-1, 1-2, 2-3 etc upto 9-10 the maximum

Comment: in otherwords 0.* 1.* 2.* etc?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the number right when testing for `End`, and then deal with that completed block of text.

For instance, extract the integer part of the captured number and then subtract it from the number to see whether it is `<= 0.9`. Then that integer, or it + 1, is used for the file name.  It is here where we also need to clear the buffer.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'data.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @buff;
while (<$fh>) 
{
    push @buff, $_;

    if (my ($num) = /^End\s+(.*)/) 
    {
        my $N = int $num;
        my $fout = 'name_'.  ($num - $N <= 0.9 ? $N : $N+1 ) . '.txt';

        open my $fh_out, '>>', $fout or die "Can't open $fout: $!";
        print $fh_out $_ for @buff;

        @buff = (); 
    }   
}
```

This expects that `End num` is surely the end of a block. The file is opened in for append (`>>`) since blocks with the number in the same range should all go in the file for that range. Also, opening a file in append mode creates a new file if it doesn't already exist so that takes care of both possibilities.

Tested with data including multiple blocks within same range and a block with `N.95`.

Comment: Actually the floating value can repeat and should get appended to existing entries if any in the created file for a given range.

Comment: @SenthilKumar  Ah ... this is a kind of thing to mention in the question, no?  It's an easy fix though: open the file for append, with mode `>>`.  If it doesn't exist it gets created, otherwise it appends.  Edited.

Comment: @SenthilKumar  Edited comments a bit, I hope they are clear.  Tested with repeating ranges as well.  This uses the same approach as your code except that handling of numbers is cleaned up and simplified, along with the extraction of Start-End blocks. Please let me know if I should add more explanation.

Comment: @SenthilKumar  You are welcome.  The code you show has good ideas but there is no need here to do such detailed processing, so I thought that it would be constructive to offer a simplification. I edited a few comments in the answer a little.  Please let me know if more commentary would be useful or if anything is unclear.